# Android .jar file requires referenced project to be opened

Tags: android, jar, android-library

I'm very confused about adding external .jar files to my project.

I downloaded https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh library project.

After importing it to Eclipse, I cleaned & built it.

After that, in the bin/ folder of the library project, there is a .jar file.

Next I copied this .jar file to the /libs directory of my project from which I want to reference it.

As far as I understood, from now on there is no need to keep the library project in my workspace, because i added the .jar file to my project.

Picture of the projects tree:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7w4tzis8v1vv4aj/jarProblem.png

When I'm running the referencing project with the library project open : no issues.

As soon as i close the library project: NullPointerException <- seems not to find the library.

I already tried every possible combination of build path configuration but I can't get my main project to be built with the pulltorefresh project closed.

I thought it was the sense of a .jar file to distribute a library without having to attach the source files.

It should work the same as the android-support-v4.jar ... for which i don't have the source code either.

What am I missing here ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between a jar file and a library project.

Jar files can contain only code, no android resources.  These just need to be placed in your libs folder and linked in.

Library projects can contain Android resources.  They need to be compiled as Android libraries in Eclipse, and kept around as their own project.  You then tell your main project that it references this one.  Its necessary to keep the library project around because it needs to build the /gen files from it for your resources to be right.  It also needs to be able to grab the contents of its assets folder.

Given that this library has a res folder, its an Android library project and can not be used as a simple jar.